# Laravel through model relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables with this order:

1. School `it has -> id`
2. SchoolSemester `it has -> school_id`
3. SemesterClass `it has -> semester_id`

Now I am trying to make relation between `School` and `SemesterClass` in order to get list of classes of each school as well as name of schools in each class.

based on [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) i have this relationships:

**school model**

```
class School extends Model
{
    public function semesters() {
        return $this->hasMany(SchoolSemester::class);
    }

    public function classes() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(SemesterClass::class, SchoolSemester::class);
    }
}
```

**SchoolSemester model**

```
class SchoolSemester extends Model
{
    public function school() {
        return $this->belongsTo(School::class);
    }

    public function classes() {
        return $this->hasMany(SemesterClass::class, 'semester_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**SemesterClass model**

```
class SemesterClass extends Model
{
    public function school() {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(School::class, SchoolSemester::class, 'school_id', 'id');
    }

    public function semester() {
        return $this->belongsTo(SchoolSemester::class, 'semester_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $class = SemesterClass::with(['school', 'teacher', 'teacher.user', 'students'])->findOrFail($id);
    dd($class);
    //return view('admin.Classes.show', compact('class'));
}
```

**Results**

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

Your intermediate table is `school_semester`, laravel will find the foreign_key `school_semester_id` by default, however, your foreign_key is `semester_id`, so you need to **specify the foreign_key** in `hasManyThrough`:

```php
    public function classes() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            SemesterClass::class, 
            SchoolSemester::class
            'school_id', // Foreign key on school_semesters table...
            'semester_id', // Foreign key on classes table...
            'id', // Local key on schools table...
            'id' // Local key on school_semesters table...
        );
     }
```

And change your `hasOneThrough` code like this:

```php
 public function school() {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
             School::class, 
             SchoolSemester::class, 
             'id',
             'id',
             'semester_id',
             'school_id' );
    }
```

#### Another Solution:

Because the reverse is just the concatenation of two BelongsTo relationships, so you can just put the `belongsTo` in SchoolSemester and School Model.
And get the relationship like this:

```php
SemesterClass::with(['semester.school'])
```

Or you can define a mutator in SemesterClass Model:

```php
protected $appends = ['school'];

public function getSchoolAttribute() {
    return $this->semester->school;
}
```